# sfdx-cli convert - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' post rollback

Tags: sfdx-plugin, cli, pipelines

today I updated the sfdx-cli from version 7.143.0 to version 7.149.1; then I had to revert back (I performed an npm install --global sfdx-cli@7.143.0) because of some node dependencie s- atm I cannot update node.

Since I reverted back I'm facing "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'" when performing an sfdx force:source:convert.

Do you have any clue on how to solve this issue? this code is run within a gitlab pipeline.

Thank you very much for your support